# Effect of determinization on the time complexity of Turing machines

Tags: turing-machines, time-complexity

Suppose I assume that the complexity of a non-deterministic Turing machine $N$ is $T(n)$, $n$ is the length of the input string. What would be the time complexity of a deterministic Turing machine $D$ equivalent to $N$?

Comment: That depends on $N$. For the worst case, you might want to check e.g. the [Exponential Time Hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_time_hypothesis). There is not a strong theorem like [Savitch's Teorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitch%27s_theorem) for space complexity, establishing a similar tight connection.

Comment: How do you construct $D$ from $N$?